# What is the explicit matrix for tensors $V \otimes V^*$

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

Notice the natural isomorphism $V \otimes V^* \simeq End(V)$, I wonder what is the explicit matrix given by $v \otimes v^*$? (where $v^* \in V^*$ is the dual space of V).

Comment: $V^*$ is the dual space, which makes sense. But is there a relation between $v$ and $v^*$, or are they completely unrelated and two arbitrary vectors of their respective spaces?

Comment: If $n$ is the dimension of $V$ then $\mathrm{End}(V)$ is isomorphic to $M_{n\times n}(k)$ as a $k$-algebra, but this isomorphism is not canonical. If you want to know "the" matrix corresponding to $v\otimes v^*$ you need to first choose a basis. If you have chose a basis so that $v$ has components $v_i$ and $v^*$ has components $w_i$ in the dual basis then the matrix of $v\otimes v^*$ is given by $(v\otimes v^*)_{ij} = v_iw_j$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix a basis $\mathcal{B}^* = (e_1,\ldots, e_n)$ for $V$, and write $v = \sum_{i=1}^n a^ie_i$. If $v^* = \sum_{j=1}^n b_je^j$, where $(e^1,\ldots, e^n)$ is the dual basis to the original one chosen, recalling that $(v\otimes v^*)(w) = v^*(w)v$, we compute the matrix of $v\otimes v^*$ with the usual algorithm: evaluate it at $e_j$, write it as a combination of the original basis, and place the coefficients in columns. We have $$(v\otimes v^*)(e_j) = v^*(e_j)v = b_jv = \sum_{i=1}^n a^ib_je_i.$$So the matrix is $[v\otimes v^*]_{\mathcal{B}} = (a^ib_j)_{i,j=1}^n$. If $[v]_{\mathcal{B}}$ is the column vector consisting of the components of $v$ relative to $\mathcal{B}$ and $[v^*]_{\mathcal{B}}$ is the column vector consisting of the components of $v^*$ relative to $\mathcal{B}^*$, then $$[v\otimes v^*]_{\mathcal{B}} = [v]_{\mathcal{B}}[v^*]_{\mathcal{B}}^\top.$$